# Select multiple categories in form (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, fields-for

I've got this tripbuilder which i want to assign categories to. So I've set up the models as where a trip can have any(or more) categories that are in the category table in my database. However; i have no idea how i can set up the form allowing a user to select categories via checkbox. Since fields_for doesn't sound like a solid way to go in this case (Because i want to see all the categories with a checkbox and select as many categories as i want). Can anyone help me out?

I've tried this form:

```
<%= form_for @trip, :html => {:multipart => true} do |a| %> 
    <%= a.label :title, "Routetitel" %>
    <%= a.text_field :title %>

    <%= a.label :description, "Omschrijving" %>
    <%= a.text_area :description %>

    <%= a.fields_for :categories do |cat| %>
        <%= cat.check_box :name %>
    <% end %>

    <%= a.submit 'Verstuur' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to setup the relationship between trip and category like this:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Then you can build the form like this:

```
<%= form_for @trip, :html => {:multipart => true} do |a| %> 
    <%= a.label :title, "Routetitel" %>
    <%= a.text_field :title %>

    <%= a.label :description, "Omschrijving" %>
    <%= a.text_area :description %>

    <% Category.all.each do |cat| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "trip[category_ids][]", cat.id, @trip.catergory_ids.include?(cat.id)
    <% end %>

    <%= a.submit 'Verstuur' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well! I managed to get the form output as i wanted so that's a big plus! However, when i try to call @trip.categories in my trip show it gives back an empty array. Whilst i just added 3 categories to a new trip.

I can't figure out how to call the categories_trips table via my console so i can't check if it actually saved anything though.

Comment: I don't think you can check categories_trips table with Rails Consle. Instead, a db console should be used. You can also check the log to see if there are any SQLs insert data to categories_trips.

Comment: Got any tips on the DB console thingie? I'm rather new to all of this.
And by the way, is the @trip.categories call correct?

Comment: Edit: I foolishy just copied your code missing the "product" in the checkbox tag. I fixed this by changing it to "trip".  However i get the following error now:
SQLite3::ConstraintException: categories_trips.created_at may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "categories_trips" ("trip_id", "category_id") VALUES (45, 7)

Comment: table categories_trips should only has two columns: "trip_id", "category_id".

Comment: You, sir. Are my hero! Thanks! One more question: Do i need a dependent destroy with this or is it done auto?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done by using select tag and `multiple` attribute of select tag.

```
    <% = a.select :categories, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :include_blank => true', :multiple => "multiple" %>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific based on the case i've given? How do i do it in rails? Do i get all the categories and loop through them? If so; How do i save them along with the trip?

Comment: look at the answer now plaese, hopefully it will help you.

Comment: It does. It does however not give me the option to set multiple answers. And with that i would prefer checkboxes. Could you give me that last push? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please Modify your fields_for as described below and check !!!!

```
<%= a.fields_for "categories[]" do |cat| %>
    <%= cat.check_box :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Nope! "`@trip[categories' is not allowed as an instance variable name"

Thanks though!